# How to get a recursive list of functions within a procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have a list of procedures and I can get a list of functions within those procedures.

But I need to create a recursive way to see if there are functions within those functions. Here's how I started:

```
select  referencing_id,
        object_name(referencing_id) as referencing_object_name,
        object_name(sed.referenced_id) as referenced_object_name
from    sys.sql_expression_dependencies as sed
inner join sys.objects as obj
on      sed.referencing_id = obj.object_id
inner join #temp a
on      a.procedure_name = object_name(referencing_id)
where   referenced_entity_name in (select name
                                   from   sys.objects
                                   where  type_desc like '%function%')
order by referencing_object_name
```

This code gives me a list of procedures and functions with them.

How can I go a step further here to make sure I'm doing a recursive on the functions I found here so that if there are functions within those functions, I also see that too?

NOTE: I don't need to do a recursive of the actual procedures. The list of procedures are already all the procedures I need. I'm only looking for the functions within functions.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the same way you did your procedures query, instead of the `#temp a` which I don't really know what is that since you didn't say. So, you'll be joining the `sys.objects` where the referencing type is a function and self-join it where the referenced type is also a function. Here's your query updated to work for Functions only:

```
select  referencing_id,
        object_name(referencing_id) as referencing_object_name,
        object_name(sed.referenced_id) as referenced_object_name
from    sys.sql_expression_dependencies as sed
inner join sys.objects as obj
on      sed.referencing_id = obj.object_id
inner join sys.objects a
on      a.name = object_name(referencing_id) and a.type_desc like '%function%'
where   referenced_entity_name in (select name
                                   from   sys.objects
                                   where  type_desc like '%function%')
order by referencing_object_name
```

If you want to get the list of functions referenced by the procedures, that references other functions it could go like this: (Note: I am not 100% sure this is the best way for this though):

```
select  referencing_id,
        object_name(referencing_id) as referencing_object_name,
        object_name(sed.referenced_id) as referenced_object_name
from    sys.sql_expression_dependencies as sed
inner join sys.objects as obj
on      sed.referencing_id = obj.object_id
inner join sys.objects a
on      a.name = object_name(referencing_id) and a.type_desc like '%function%'
where   referenced_entity_name in (select name
                                   from   sys.objects
                                   where  type_desc like '%function%')
        and object_name(sed.referenced_id) in (select  object_name(sed.referenced_id) as referenced_object_name
                                        from    sys.sql_expression_dependencies as sed
                                        inner join sys.objects as obj
                                        on      sed.referencing_id = obj.object_id
                                        inner join sys.procedures a
                                        on      a.name = object_name(referencing_id)
                                        where   referenced_entity_name in (select name
                                                                           from   sys.objects
                                                                           where  type_desc like '%function%'))
```